# IRC bot connecting to random servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, irc

Well the bot I made in python and it is connecting to random servers. I cant figure out why. so far this code is mishmash of other projects so maybe I'm overlooking something. basicly I want it to connect to irc.rizon.net join #brook_nise then lurk there.

I conect to these servers when I run my script:

```
irc.rizon.io    
irc.sxci.net    
irc.broke-it.com    
irc.rizon.sexy
```

.

```
import socket

network = 'irc.rizon.net'
network = network.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
USR = "USER boxxxy boxxxy boxxxy :boxxxy\r\n"
PAS = '/msg NickServ IDENTIFY pass\r\n'
JOI = 'JOIN #brook_nise\r\n'
pi  = 'PING'
po  = 'PONG'

PING = pi.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
PONG = po.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
USER = USR.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
PASS = PAS.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
JOIN = JOI.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')


irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
print (irc.recv ( 4096 ))


irc.send (USER)
irc.send (PASS)
irc.send (JOIN)

while True:
    data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
    if data.find ( PING ) != -1:
        irc.send ( PONG + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )

    print (data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because irc.rizon.net is a geobalanced DNS record. It checks where your bot is coming from and then automatically assigns it a server to connect to.

Basically there is no such server as 'irc.rizon.net', if you always want the same one (you don't) then just specify one of the servers you have listed.